# How can Container content be rendered in a C# Windows Application?

Tags: c#, windows

I have a C# WinForms Application with a Collection (ArrayList) whose content I want to view in a Grid and want to find an easy way to do this.

Comment: Your question; it makes no sense.  Winforms, or WPF?  Define "Container"--what is its Type, and how do you want to display it in a "grid"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, tough without specifics, but you could loop through the arraylist and put the data into a DataTable, then bind that DataTable to a GridView control.